# Getting jquery error like "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a JavaScript error saying `$tabAcc.removeClass is not a function` when executing the code below. What could be the issue?

```
var $tabAcc = '',
    $tabtoShow = '',
    $tabSelectAcc = '',
    $tabtoShowSelected = '',
    $tabSelectAcc = '',
    $tabBilling = '',
    $tabtoShowBilling = '',
    $tabSelectBilling = '',
    $tabtoShowBillingSelected = '';
$(".tabAcc").mouseover(function () {
    $tabAcc = $(".tabAcc");
    $tabtoShow = $tabAcc.children('.tabListMenu');
    $tabAcc.removeClass('tabAcc').addClass('tabHoverAcc');
    $tabtoShow.show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $tabAcc.removeClass('tabHoverAcc').addClass('tabAcc');
    $tabtoShow.hide();
});
```

Comment: Check whether attr is supported in specified jquery version which your using

Comment: it's too horrible to read..

Comment: @Ravi [jsbeautifier.org/](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or the TidyUp feature on [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) is an easy way to fix that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist thank you for the links :), knew JSFiddle can format. but this Beautifier is newer to me

Answer (score 1):

you have full of mess code.

1. Make sure you have jquery libraries.
2. wrap your element in jquery object to use jquery libraries

   ```
   $($tabAcc).removeClass("classname");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If a `mouseout` event always follows a `mouseover` event, then you'll be fine, because `$tabAcc` will actually reference a jQuery object. The problem will come if you get a `mouseout` event before a `mouseover` event, since then your `$tabAcc` variable will simply be an empty string.

The String class in JavaScript object doesn't have a `removeClass` function, so you'll get an error. Assuming that you're not dynamically adding `.tabAcc` elements to the page, you could modify your code to look like this:

```
var $tabAcc = $('.tabAcc'),
    $tabtoShow,
    $tabSelectAcc,
    $tabtoShowSelected,
    $tabSelectAcc,
    $tabBilling,
    $tabtoShowBilling,
    $tabSelectBilling,
    $tabtoShowBillingSelected;
$tabAcc.mouseover(function () {
    $tabtoShow = $tabAcc.children('.tabListMenu');
    $tabAcc.removeClass('tabAcc').addClass('tabHoverAcc');
    $tabtoShow.show();
}).mouseout(function () {
    $tabAcc.removeClass('tabHoverAcc').addClass('tabAcc');
    $tabtoShow.hide();
});
```

That way you're caching the result of `$('.tabAcc')` (a minor performance improvement, since you only call it once), and you can be sure that the `$tabAcc` variable will reference a jQuery object, and therefore have the `removeClass` function, inside your event handler functions.